# How to deploy a site that is not at the root of a server with DocPad?

Tags: docpad

I'm using DocPad to make a demo site and i want to deploy it at for example:
http://www.example.com/demo/
but when i use `docpad generate --env static`, links are relative to the root of the server not demo directory so links are broken. What can i do ? is there a metadata to declare somewhere ?

EDIT:
In this case, I use the Twitter Bootsrap skeleton, so for example links in the main navigation in the default layout looks like:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav">
    <% for document in @getCollection('pages').toJSON(): %>
      <li class="<%= 'active'  if @document.url is document.url %>">
        <a href="<%= document.url %>"><%= document.title %></a>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can we please see your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a small plugin which does the job, there's probably a better solution but it works fine:

```
# Export Plugin
module.exports = (BasePlugin) ->
  # Define Plugin
  class absolutePathPlugin extends BasePlugin
    # Plugin Name
    name: 'absolutepath'
    config:
      url: "/"

    renderAfter: (opts,next) ->
      docpad = @docpad
      if 'static' in docpad.getEnvironments()
        docpad.log 'debug', 'Writing absolute urls'
        href = 'href="' + @config.url
        src = 'src="' + @config.url
        database = docpad.getCollection('html')
        database.forEach (document) ->
          content = document.get('contentRendered')
          if /href="\//.test(content)
            content = content.replace(/href="\//g, href)
          if /src="\//.test(content)
            content = content.replace(/src="\//g, src)
          document.set('contentRendered',content)
        next()?
      else
        next()?

      # Chain
      @
```

And in my `docpad.coffee` file, I just have to configure the url and if you use the cleanUrls plugin, you have to adapt the getRedirectTemplate function to take the absolute url into account:

```
plugins:
  absolutepath:
    url: "http://www.example.com/demo/"
  cleanurls:
    getRedirectTemplate: (document) ->
      absolutepath = docpadConfig.plugins.absolutepath.url.slice(0, - 1) 
      """
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>#{document.get('title') or 'Redirect'}</title>
          <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=#{absolutepath + document.get('url')}">
        </head>
        <body>
          This page has moved. You will be automatically redirected to its new location. If you aren't forwarded to the new page, <a href="#{absolutepath + document.get('url')}">click here</a>.
        </body>
      </html>
      """
```

Comment: Sweet. If you've answered your own question be sure to click the tick mark next to your answer so people know everything is all solved and good :) See the "accepted answer" stuff here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask :)

Comment: By the way, awesome solution.

Comment: This solution is fine for me, but i wasn't sure it was the better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to transform all the absolute URLs to relative ones so the site works from any path prefix (`/`, `/path/`, or `/some/other/path/`) without rebuilding.  Think gh-pages with a custom domain.

[Here's a grunt task](https://github.com/hurrymaplelad/grunt-relative-root) to do the transformation on HTML and CSS after a static docpad generation.  It's currently built on regex replacement inspired by @Dharma's docpad plugin.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, not sure what other jazz is happening above.  It's unfortunate that this is a grunt plugin, which means I need to run Grunt now (this site keeps expanding).  Why isn't there a "@document.pathToRoot" or something in DocPad?

Answer (score 0):

This is one area where DocPad could step up.

So far the most popular way people get around this is to use `<%- @site.url+@document.url %>` everywhere, however that isn't ideal of course due to the finicky nature of it. There is a gist that showcases this in more detail here: https://gist.github.com/3939146

Perhaps what DocPad needs to do is add a `absoluteUrl` attribute for files/documents which is generated from the `site.url` automatically. Then we could do `<%- @document.absoluteUrl %>` instead. Created an issue for this here: https://github.com/bevry/docpad/issues/402

Comment: Is the solution in the gist would also work for all urls like ico files or stylesheets declared in layouts ? My solution is a bit brutal but i'm sure to get to all links.

Comment: @Dharma you can use a solution like https://gist.github.com/4166806 to set meta data for non-documents, or we can just check the urls within our middleware as well